# How to generate random embed image url

Tags: php, url, png, embed, temporary-files

I'm trying to hide my image url including dir path. I tried base64 but it always shows the same url, I need a different one everytime I hit refresh. I then tried to create a temporary one using tempnam, but it only adds some characters at the end of the link and don't change the dir path.

I also tried createimagefrompng but it gives me either my website with no picture, or just a picture of a white frame.

When my player goes on the page, the page generate a random number from 1 to 5 and letter A or B, go in folder "A" or "B" and search for the picture with the generated number in that folder.

The Problem is the picture url is images/A/1.png, I want it to be random so he can't use a script to refresh until he gets A/3.

And I want it to be different everytime because he could find A/3 embed url and use the script to find that embed url.

Thank you!
Jessie

Comment: im a little confused, if the random url maps to your images, you could still simply refresh the page until you get the one you want.

Comment: Yes but I want the url to be different so I cannot use an autorefresh script that will stop on a specific url

Comment: would all images being `<img  src="img.php">` and img.php serve a random file file work?

Comment: if I can have a different image with it with a random url yes but i'm not sure I understand how :/

Comment: its the same url, but servers different images,  that's why i'm checking, its still not clear to me what is going on.

Comment: ohh yeah if I can have one image url that can show different images that works!

Comment: Ok so after a little testing I see what you mean, by using the createimagefrompng I have the php link so no way to find the image url. But I have the issue where I either get my website but the picture doesn't show up, or I have lots of symbols and characters, or I see the picture but not the rest of my website (black background)

Comment: Ok managed to include it on the page properly, using ?img=001 at the end of the php. But then the url contains the number which I don't want :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to finally make it work!

I'm using a mix of things I've already tried.

So first the base64encode was great, but it always had the same url which I didn't want.

So I searched on how create a new encoding that I could make random and found that code: https://gist.github.com/LogIN-/e451ab0e8738138bc60b

I then generate a random key and encode the image link using that random key.

I then call an php image using createimagefrompng and put the key and encoded image link in the php url (www.example.com/image.php?encoded=jsnda9d9832rm&key=emd39023)

And then in that php decode the url using the key and show the image ^^

Hope it can helps other, also if you see something I could change so my code will be lighter or have better performance please don't hesitate :)